# Use known methods of generic objects

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I'm having a class receiving 2 unknown, generic Objects x and y. I have to compare these to objects if they are comparable. I figured out that I can check if the Objects implements the `Comparable` interface by using `instanceof`, but I don't know how I can use the `.compareTo` method although I know that the Object implements them-

What I want to do is basically this with x and y being generic Objects:

```
public void someMethod(E x, E y) {
    if (x instanceof Comparable && y instanceof Comparable) {
        if(x.compareTo(y) < 0){    //The method compareTo(E) is undefined for the type E
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking you can (and should) cast the objects safely to use them as you need.

```
 if (x instanceof Comparable && y instanceof Comparable) {
    Comparable c1 = (Comparable) x;
    Comparable c2 = (Comparable) y;        
    if(c1.compareTo(c2) < 0){
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know that casting to an interface is possible, thanks! Correct answer, as I did not know if the generic element implmentents Comparable.

Comment: raw types should not be used

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a generic type bound. Right now `E` could be any `Object` type, but it looks like you want to restrict it to any type that implements `Comparable`, which would look like:

```
public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void someMethod(T x, T y) {
    if (x.compareTo(y) < 0) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The alternative answers that suggest casting are correct, but not a nice solution: if you know that 'x' and 'y' implement `Comparable`, you should restrict them as such.

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the method like

```
public <E extends Comparable<E>> void someMethod(E x, E y)
```

so in your method you can be sure to use the compareTo method.

Comment: Good idea, but it looks like he has an ```E``` type bound at the class level already, and so having having one for someMethod is going to shadow the other (which isn't very nice, and often prohibited in coding styles). Simply changing ```E``` to another identifier (e.g. ```T```) would fix this.